# Having an error 'Error: TypeError: Already read'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am very new to ember. I have created a drop down list with `<PowerSelect>`

```
<PowerSelect
          class="uk-select" id="form-ReadSecurity"
          @options={{this.secReadOptions}}
          @selected={{this.changeset.secLevel}}
          @onChange={{this.selectReadSecurity}} as |option|>
          {{option.description2}}
        </PowerSelect>
```

and whenever I change the option and try to save using the save button I am getting an error

> 'Error: TypeError: Already read'

I have other drop down list too which is not created using `<PowerSelect>` but it is working fine.

Can anyone help me understand the issue?

Comment: hello! and welcome to ember-stackoverflow.  

Do you have a stack trace for your error? where is the error coming from? (for those not familiar with power-select, or where it comes from (me   ) )

Comment: I agree with @NullVoxPopuli, we’re going to need a bit more code to help here… We don’t know what `secReadOptions` nor `selectReadSecurity` do, for example.